# Different flow for different web api endpoints

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3, identityserver4

How do I setup Web API Endpoints to use different grant types coming from IdentityServer?

Right now I have for Startup is:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions()
{
   Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
   RequiredScopes = new[] { "public", "read", "write" }
});
```

Controller:

```
// Assuming to access this endpoint you need to have client id/secret (client credential flow)
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
   return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}

// Assuming to access this endpoint you need to have username/password (password flow)
[ResourceAuthorization("read")]
public string Get(int id)
{
   return "value";
}
```

Of course one endpoint can only have one grant type since it doesn't make sense if a Client Flow endpoint will also allow a Password flow.

Is this a bad structure?

Should I just separate the public apis (credential flow), password flow endpoints and internal endpoints (not expose to outside company infrastructure) to a different projects?

How do I specify the scope for different endpoints? (e.g one endpoint needs public and one needs read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very bad. You're coupling authentication flow concerns with your API. Rather define different scopes per client and use those scopes to limit which clients can use which resources. You can do claims based authorization based on scope. Check [this](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/samples/SystemWeb/ClaimsAuthorizeSample) out.

Comment: But what if the client authenticated using client flow? Will the ResourceAuthorization still work?

Comment: As I understood ResourceAuthorization should be used if you have a User involved meaning the client login logs in using password flow and use ScopeAuthorization if no user is involved. Looking at the ScopeAuthorization, it says it was deprecated so should I use the former?

Comment: ^ https://speakerdeck.com/leastprivilege/web-api-authorization-and-access-control-done-right-ndc-oslo-2014?slide=43

Comment: It should still work, all those authorize attributes do is check to see whether those claims exist in the bearer token, scope just as well appears as a claim in a JWT.